# Laravel 7 - artisan seed Target class [DatabaseSeeder] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, laravel-7

I'm trying to seed my "DatabaseSeeder.php' But when I try to run
`php artisan db:seed`
I get the error:

> Target class [DatabaseSeeder] does not exist.

My code in "DatabaseSeeder.php" looks like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 3)->create()->each(function($u) {
            $u->questions()
              ->saveMany(
                  factory(App\Question::class, rand(1, 5))->make()
              );
        });        
    }
}
```

What I tried so far:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

```
php artisan optimize
```

**Note: I don't have a User-Made seeder, I'm trying to use the default one (DatabaseSeeder.php), but for some reason, it's telling me that it doesn't exist.**

Comment: Have you made any customizations to your composer.json? Specifically to the "autoload" section?

Comment: add namespace Database\Seeds; at top

Comment: @kurtFriars No, I haven't...

The "autoload" section looks like this:

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Illuminate\\Container\\": ""
        }
    },
```
Although I remember having a "classmap" section, but it must've been deleted when I ran 
```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: @Monika It did not work

Comment: @JwedaAbdusalam did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: @KurtFriars I'm sorry for the late reply... though it did not work, I still get the same error.

Comment: I have deleted my answer.

Comment: @Monika had the right answer here.

Answer (score 1):

With Laravel 7, the composer.json needs the classmap reference in the autoload mapping, because the default seed folder doesn't respect PSR-4: `database/seeds` (see [Laravel Documentation - Database: Seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding#introduction))

Check to have this in the composer.json:

```
"classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
```

And run `composer dump-autoload`

See this similar error: [Target class [DatabaseSeeder] does not exist - Laravel 7 and Composer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66600842/target-class-databaseseeder-does-not-exist-laravel-7-and-composer-2)

Comment: or just run composer dumpautoload. it will work too