# Target class [DatabaseSeeder] does not exist - Laravel 7 and Composer 2

Tags: composer-php, laravel-7

I have an app with laravel 7, and i upgrade composer 1.10 to composer 2.0, and i have this problem:

```php
   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

  Target class [DatabaseSeeder] does not exist.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:807
    803|
    804|         try {
    805|             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    806|         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  > 807|             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    808|         }
    809|
    810|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    811|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

      +37 vendor frames
  38  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I tried many solution (even for Laravel 8 ...) without success.

Here is the autoload of the composer.json

```
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "DatabaseSeeder\\": "database/seeds"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    }
```

Thx !

### EDIT

Here is what I just found: When I add in the composer.json :

```
  "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories",
            "Database\\Seeds\\": "database/seeds",
            "DatabaseSeeder\\": "database/seeds/",
} },
```

and that I modify line 84 of SeedCommand.php 'src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php', it work !!!

```
$class = $this->laravel->make($this->input->getOption('class'));
```

by

```
$class = $this->laravel->make('Database\\Seeds\\DatabaseSeeder');
```

But this is absolutely not maintainable...
So the problem is, there is a problem when DatabaseSeeder is set.

6An idea ?

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? Is this even related to Composer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution:
Laravel documention : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding#introduction

> All seed classes are stored in the database/seeds directory.... By default, a DatabaseSeeder class is defined for you.

This folder is not compatible with the PSR-4, so you have to use the classmap in the composer.json with Laravel 7.

It is therefore also necessary to remove the namespaces in the files of seeds.

Here is my composer json:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: helpers.php file doesn't required if you don't use that file anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows:

- I followed what the documentation said regarding Sedeers and factories
- I ran composer dump-autoload
- Update composer to version 2